# Export to CSV File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

I'm following that railcast episode. It's working perfect but while I export to csv file that unable add .csv extension means that it's store like **products** not as **products.csv**.

I want to store like **products.csv** how can do that means how can i add extension during saving that file that take automatically add extension during save csv file.

**Update**

[image]

When I export CSV file then I will open popup like above image. but I want **products.csv** in the **Name:**

**Update 2**

> Controller

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data @customers.to_csv }
    format.xls
  end


View


<%= link_to "CSV", "/admin/partners?id=#{params[:id]}&start_date=#{params[:start_date]}&end_date=#{params[:end_date]}&format=csv" %> 

<%= link_to "Excel", "/admin/partners?id=#{params[:id]}&start_date=#{params[:start_date]}&end_date=#{params[:end_date]}&format=xls" %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Add the part of the code where you are saving the file.

Comment: @DipakPanchal See my answer below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
        format.csv { send_data @report.to_csv, filename: @report.name + ".csv"} #to export csv
end
```

In the view

```
<%= link_to 'CSV', report_path(report, format: :csv)%>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this, it should work.

## In view

---

```
<%= link_to "Products CSV", products_path(:format => 'csv') %>
```

---

## In Controller

```
def index
  products = Product.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.csv do
      send_data products.to_csv
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: use ".csv" something like
`<%= link_to "CSV", "/admin/partners?id=#{params[:id]}&start_date=#{params[:start_date]}&end_date=#{params[:end_date]}.csv" %>`

Comment: can you provide output of `rake routes` for this action Or check do you have "(.:format)" in route